# how to get inclusive and exclusive price in products collections magento 2?

Tags: magento2, price

> Here i am trying to get the inclusive and exclusive price in products
>   collections magento 2.If anyone any have idea please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show price including and excluding on product listing you can simply enable the configuration for it.
Stores-> Configuration-> Sales-> Tax-> Price Display Settings (Display Product Prices In Catalog)

If you want to get it code for a perticular product, You could use something like

```
$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount()
```

This gets you the price with no tax into store currency